# How to manage dependency on servlet-api?

Tags: java, maven-2, guice

We have a web maven module that is compiled to a war, and thus doesn't need to include the servlet-api jar directly. We use `<scope>provided</scope>` for this.

The problem arises when I try to write a small main() to test one of my classes. This is not a unit test, but rather resides with the code itself.

This fails on `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  final Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new StandardModule());
  // StandardModule is our standard module, with bindings to 
  // something that rightfully depends on servlet API
  ...
}
```

Besides splitting my module to two or three different modules, is there an easy workaround I haven't thought of?

Perhaps the best solution is to move this tester to the test code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `<scope>test</scope>` if you want to have it for tests. However `provided` works fine for me in Eclipse - it is added to the classpath.

Comment: Scope:compile is the default scope, which is not what they want (because that would add the jar to the war). scope:test should work

Comment: I moved the code to the 'test' folder (in Intellij, not Eclipse, btw), and it works like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: then IntelliJ has problems with Maven ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you use eclipse with m2eclipse, `<scope>provided</scope>` will be resolved correctly and your main class will compile and run properly.